# Is transaction_id of paypal Mass Payout Item mutable?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#payouts-item_get api to request my payouts through Paypal.

My question is: when a payout item changes its status from i.e. SUCCESS to REFUNDED, does transaction_id change as well (i.e. to the ID of a refund transaction)?

It is not clear from the API docs; the only thing clear is that transaction_id could be empty in some cases. They also call it "The" transaction_id, so it kind of hints it's immutable after it is set, although it's only an assumption.

Comment: To add some context, I'm asking because as far as I know a payout and a refund are two different transactions.

Comment: A PayPal transaction and a refund of that transaction are two separate things. Each will have their own ID. This is the important detail to be clear on, the rest can be tested yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, I found that the transaction_id of the result of  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#payouts-item_get changes.

Before cancellation, the transaction_id is the original transaction id, but after cancellation, it becomes the transaction_id of the cancellation transaction.

It seems that the rules for these changes aren't documented, and we should read their "transaction id" in docs as "some transaction id that is related to the original transaction, or maybe the original transaction.

It's not the *latest* transaction either; the latest is the fee refund transaction.